# Load another view when click on a image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for a project. I set controller A as my default controller in routes.php. So in this controller A it will load my home page.

If I want to access another view from the homepage for example about or contact, how do I go about doing it??

Comment: Useful documentation: [CodeIgniter Controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/yourcontroller/yourfunction">About Page
```

Now you have yourcontroller that has the yourfunction in it, from within this function you can load the view for about page, like:

```
function yourfunction() {
  $this->load->view('your_about_view_page_name");
}
```

And that shall work. Hope it helps

Comment: do i put that function within the main controller for my main page or do i create another controller to put that? Another question, if i want to use base url() instead, how do i go about doing it? Sorry for the noobness